# B2B LWR: Phone number field in Shipping Address checkout form

Tags: fields, address, lwr, b2b, phone

In B2B LWR Checkout page there are 2 properties for Phone Number in the Shipping Address component configuration, plus there is a standard field for it in the ContactPointAddress object, PhoneNumber.

However, I am not able to see it in the standard form even having the permissions to read/edit the field and having configured the properties.

Is this an LWR bug or am I missing something?

[image: LWR B2B Checkout, Shipping Address component]